# asp.net mvc regular expression double quotes

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

How can I put " in this regular expression

Regex PhRegEx = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9-+_,(): ]*$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a [multiline string literal](http://www.kowitz.net/archive/2007/03/06/the-c-string-literal), you should double the quote character:

```
Regex PhRegEx = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9-+_,():"" ]*$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```